# Java Multicast send and receive

Tags: java, networking, multicast

Working on a little app in Java.  Suppose I have three nodes, A, B and C,  Each is listening on a multicast socket to the same group.  Suppose one of them needs to send a message to that group, can it merely pop that message out on the same socket on which it's listening or does it need to create a second socket connected to the group and transmit on that? Have not yet googled me up a definitive answer on that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can use the same socket for sending and receiving.